# Toolbar menu appear in hardware menu key in fragment

Tags: android, toolbar, menuitem

I used tool bar in fragment. but the menu always appear in hardware button. am also tried with view configuration "**sHasPermanentMenuKey**" but it still show in hardware menu. How to make the menu item to be appear in toolbar instead of hardware button? Thank you.

//fragment onCreate method

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        try {
            ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(getActivity());
            Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
            if (menuKeyField != null) {
                menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
                menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }
```

//fragment onCreateOtionsMenu

```
  @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // TODO your code to hide item here    
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        menu.clear();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.home, menu);

    }
```

//Activity onCreate method

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
         try {
                ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(Home.this);
                Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
                if (menuKeyField != null) {
                    menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
                    menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
}
```

// menu item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_filter"
        android:title="@string/action_filter"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_filter"
        />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_map"
        android:title="@string/action_map"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_map"
        />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
        />

</menu>
```

I tried with FragmentActivity and AppCompatActivity but its not working.

Comment: See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30171548/showing-a-menu-overflow-button-in-a-toolbar

Comment: @VivekMishra thank you its not working.

Comment: Is the toolbar is completely empty or only overflow icon is missing on toolbar?

Comment: @Raghavendra completely empty. only appear on hardware button click.

Comment: can u post where exactly you are setting toolbar?

Comment: oh that was my mistake now its working i uncommented a single line. Any way thank u all.

Comment: Can you please quickly update why were u facing this? I am facing same issue but not getting what is the cause.